# MongoDB aggregation with $lookup to show only result of one field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get only object pasien_docs in result of lookup, I using match, lookup and addfield but i want get result only show array of pasien_docs:

```
Pasien.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: {
        _id: ObjectId(id)
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: 
      {
          from: "data",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "idPasien",
          as: "pasien_docs"
      }
    },
    { '$addFields': {
      'pasien_docs': {
        '$map': {
          'input': '$pasien_docs',
          'in': {
            'ecg': '$$this.ecg',
            'date': '$$this.date'
          }
        }
      }
    }}
  ]
)
```

and the result is :

```
    "data": [
    {
        "_id": "5e08a79fe34fa20a302f659f",
        "username": "rizkarahayus",
        "nama": "Rizka Rahayu",
        "__v": 0,
        "pasien_docs": [
            {
                "ecg": null,
                "date": "2020-01-21T05:22:01.901Z"
            },
            {
                "ecg": 1.03,
                "date": "2020-01-21T05:22:02.979Z"
            },
```

but i want result only show array of pasien_docs like this :

```
"pasien_docs": [
            {
                "ecg": null,
                "date": "2020-01-21T05:22:01.901Z"
            },
            {
                "ecg": 1.03,
                "date": "2020-01-21T05:22:02.979Z"
            },
```

can you help me? thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and specify the inclusion of `pasien_docs` computed field, the suppression of the `_id` field like:

```
Pasien.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: {...}
    },
    {
      $lookup: {...}
    },
    { 
     '$addFields': {...}
    },
    {
      $project: { _id: 0, pasien_docs: 1 }
    }
  ]
)
```